# tinyxml and c++ to save data

Tags: c++, xml, tags, tinyxml

I am using tinyxml to save data input by the user in a c++ console program.  I pass a save function an array of structs that look like the following

```
struct day
{
      string name;
      string note;
};
```

I have seven of these, and pass all seven to the save function that looks like the following

```
void saveData(day dayArr[])
{
    TiXmlDeclaration* declaration = new TiXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no");//Create DTD
    TiXmlDocument* doc = new TiXmlDocument;
    doc->LinkEndChild(declaration);

    TiXmlElement* week = new TiXmlElement("week");
    TiXmlElement* day = new TiXmlElement("day");
    TiXmlElement* name = new TiXmlElement("name");
    TiXmlElement* note = new TiXmlElement("note");
    TiXmlElement* tl = new TiXmlElement("tl");
    TiXmlElement* ti = new TiXmlElement("ti");
    TiXmlText* dayName = new TiXmlText("");
    TiXmlText* dayNote = new TiXmlText("");

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        dayName = new TiXmlText(dayArr[i].name.c_str());
        dayNote = new TiXmlText(dayArr[i].note.c_str());
        name->LinkEndChild(dayName);
        note->LinkEndChild(dayNote);
        day->LinkEndChild(name);
        day->LinkEndChild(note);
    }

    week->LinkEndChild(day);
    doc->LinkEndChild(week);

    doc->SaveFile("test.xml");
    cout << "SAVED";
}
```

It writes this to the file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<week>
    <day>
        <name>SundayMondayTuesdayWednesdayThursdayFridaySaturday
        </name>
        <note>
        </note>
    </day>
</week>
```

What i need is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<week>
    <day>
        <name>Sunday</name>
        <note>        </note>
    </day>
 <day>
        <name>Monday</name>
        <note>
        </note>
    </day>
 <day>
        <name>Tuesday</name>
        <note>        </note>
    </day>
 <day>
        <name>Wednesday</name>
        <note>        </note>
    </day>
 <day>
        <name>Thursday</name>
        <note>        </note>
    </day>
 <day>
        <name>Friday</name>
        <note>        </note>
    </day>
 <day>
        <name>Saturday</name>
        <note>        </note>
    </day>
</week>
```

I can't figure out how to create new elements of the day tag.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used TinyXml before but looking at the structure of the code, you need to create the day element inside your `for` loop and add it to the week element 7 times - once for each day.

Your current code only adds the day element to the week element once at the end - this is reflected in your xml output.

Taking part of your code - maybe something similar to this below. (This may not compile or be exactly correct but should provide the right idea).

```
TiXmlElement* week = new TiXmlElement("week");   
TiXmlElement* name = new TiXmlElement("name");
TiXmlElement* note = new TiXmlElement("note");
TiXmlElement* tl = new TiXmlElement("tl");
TiXmlElement* ti = new TiXmlElement("ti");
TiXmlText* dayName = new TiXmlText("");
TiXmlText* dayNote = new TiXmlText("");

for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    TiXmlElement* day = new TiXmlElement("day");
    dayName = new TiXmlText(dayArr[i].name.c_str());
    dayNote = new TiXmlText(dayArr[i].note.c_str());
    name->LinkEndChild(dayName);
    note->LinkEndChild(dayNote);
    day->LinkEndChild(name);
    day->LinkEndChild(note);
    week->LinkEndChild(day);
}

doc->LinkEndChild(week);
```

Comment: I got it.  I am learning how to use tinyxml and should have seen that ( a real d'oh moment ) Thank you so much for the help.  It isn't letting me post another answer.  But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
void saveData(std::vector<day*> vecDay)
{
    TiXmlDeclaration* declaration = new TiXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no");//Create DTD
    TiXmlDocument* doc = new TiXmlDocument;
    doc->LinkEndChild(declaration);

    TiXmlElement* week = new TiXmlElement("week");

    for(std::vector<day*>::iterator it = vecDay.begin(); it != vecDay.end(); it++)
    {
        TiXmlElement* day_ = new TiXmlElement("day");
        TiXmlElement* name = new TiXmlElement("name");
        TiXmlElement* note = new TiXmlElement("note");
        TiXmlElement* tl = new TiXmlElement("tl");
        TiXmlElement* ti = new TiXmlElement("ti");
        TiXmlText* dayName = new TiXmlText("");
        TiXmlText* dayNote = new TiXmlText("");
        dayName = new TiXmlText((*it)->name.c_str());
        dayNote = new TiXmlText((*it)->note.c_str());
        name->LinkEndChild(dayName);
        note->LinkEndChild(dayNote);
        day_->LinkEndChild(name);
        day_->LinkEndChild(note);
        week->LinkEndChild(day_);
    }

    doc->LinkEndChild(week);

    doc->SaveFile("test2.xml");
    cout << "SAVED" << endl;
}
```